# CUIT: VS 2010: i have recorded CUIT test in Windows 7 and playing back in Window XP it is failing

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I have recorded CUIT test in Windows 7 and playing back in Window XP it is failing.

Is it record click point difference in XP and 7

How to solve this limitation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always remove the Point() parameter when I use Mouse.Click. 
Try removing that param:
Old: Mouse.Click(objectName, Point(12,34));
New: Mouse.Click(objectName);

Answer (score 0):

Try you identify the control and then to click. It's much better then record.

```
Mouse.Click(control);
```